# Why can't I display an EnumProperty in a UIList?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Actually, I know how to "insert" or "add" custom properties into a UIList in blender 2.8.

[image]

But actually I'm stuck with enum and collection properties.
I don't know why I can't display them in a UIList, but If I test them outside of that, they work.

[image]

The process is simple. Create a PropertyGroup with an EnumProperty:

```
class CUSTOM_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    #name = StringProperty() -> Instantiated by default
    obj_type = StringProperty()
    obj_name = StringProperty()
    obj_id = IntProperty()
    obj_radio = StringProperty()
    obj_escala = StringProperty()    
    obj_simetria = BoolProperty()
    obj_ejemplo =  EnumProperty(default=None,
        items = [
            ('NONE', 'None', "Flat geometry"),
            ('GEOM', 'Geometry', "Use z value from shape geometry if exists"),
            ('FIELD', 'Field', "Extract z elevation value from an attribute field"),
            ('OBJ', 'Object', "Get z elevation value from an existing ground mesh")
        ])
    obj_esquina = BoolProperty()
    obj_borde = BoolProperty()
```

And add an item in some operator:

```
item = scn.custom.add()
item.name = i.name
item.obj_type = i.type 
item.obj_id = len(scn.custom)
item.obj_ejemplo = "NONE" 
item.obj_simetria = item.obj_simetria
item.obj_escala = str(round(i.scale[0],2))
```

But it doesn't work with the EnumProperty and I don't get any error.

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags when asking a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must add all de properties into de UIList class

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Drawing
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
        #split.label(text="Index: %d" % (index))
        custom_icon = "OUTLINER_OB_%s" % item.obj_type

        split.label(text=item.name) #item.name
        split.prop(item, 'obj_name', text="",  icon="MESH_CIRCLE")
        split.prop(item, 'obj_radio',text="Radio: ")
        split.prop(item, 'obj_ejemplo', text='')
        split.label(text="Escala: " + item.obj_escala)
        split.prop(item, 'obj_simetria', text="Simetria", toggle=False, slider=True, icon="CHECKMARK")
        

        split.prop(item, 'obj_esquina', text="Esquina", icon="CHECKMARK")
        
        split.prop(item, 'obj_borde', text="Borde", icon="CHECKMARK")

    

def invoke(self, context, event):
    pass
```

[image]